# BASH logic problem; difficulty testing one string variable with IF and OR

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a string `var1` which I am using in BASH. 
It can be three values

```
var1=on

var1=off
```

or `var1` can be equal to anything that is not `on` or `off`

I wish to build an if statement in BASH that tests `$var1` for its content as follows;

If the `$var1` string equals "`on`" or "`off`" then exit the if statement.
if `$var1` equals anything else continue on ...

I have tried loads of possibilities including -ne, !=, || and -o and am in a complete muddle.

Below I've pasted what I am using, what I am getting using this, and what I want.

`var1=on`

`if [[ ${var1} != 'on' || $var1 != 'off' ]]; then 
     echo var1 is NOT equal to \"on\" or \"off\". Var1 is equal to $var1 
  else
     echo var1 IS equal to \"on\". Var1 is equal to $var1
fi`

This produces;

`var1 is NOT equal to "on" or "off". Var1 is equal to on`

What I want is;

`var1 IS equal to "on". Var1 is equal to on`

Comment: What does "exit the `if` statement" mean? "Continuing on" as the alternative sounds very similar to "exiting the if statement". Perhaps some pseudocode would illustrate your situation more clearly?

Comment: Sounds very much like you want a `case` statement rather than an `if`.  Perhaps by "continue on" you mean that there is a loop here somewhere?

Comment: Hi @WilliamPursell Thanks. There's no loop. It's either `on` or `off` or anything else. Three options only. If it's anything else a help file is printed. The solution was from @fra-san in comments below and is `if [[ ${var1} != 'on' && $var1 != 'off' ]]; then print_help; exit; fi`

Comment: @WilliamPursell I couldn't get `case` to work. I tried the case solution as shown  below but didn't know if I could make a case of `not` `!` `on` or  `not` `!` `off`. It has to be the inverse to be neat and I couldn't establish if that could be done. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "introduce a value: " var1

if [[ ${var1} != 'on' && ${var1} != 'off' ]];
then
        exit
else
        echo "CORRECT"
fi
```

Comment: `var1=on;`

`if [[ ${var1} != 'on' || $var1 != 'off' ]]; then
   echo var1 is NOT equal to \"on\" or \"off\". Var1 is equal to $var1;
 else
   echo var1 IS equal to \"on\". Var1 is equal to $var1;
fi`

This produces;
`$ var1 is NOT equal to "on" or "off". Var1 is equal to on`

What I'm expecting is;
`$ var1 IS equal to "on". Var1 is equal to on`

Comment: Edited previous answer adding the case tense that would adapt to what you search.

Comment: @Kes. Here you are testing if `var1` is not equal to `on` OR `var1` is not equal to `off`. Since `var1` is not equal to `off`, the result is true and the corresponding line is printed. To test for non-equality you have to replace the `||` (OR) operator with `&&` (AND), as in `if [[ ${var1} != 'on' && $var1 != 'off' ]]; then ...`.

Comment: @fra-san thanks. I tried that already about an hour ago. Going to try again.

Comment: @Dasel thanks. The case would work but it needs to be `!=` rather than `=`

Comment: @fra-san.Thanks. That's it. I can't beleive that got me.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks. The correct answer is from fra-san in the comments above. So does that mean the answer from Dasel is right. I'll happily click the right place, I'm just not sure what to do.

Comment: I misunderstood, @Kes. Dasel, would you be willing to make the updates that fra-san suggested in this comment thread, in order to answer Dasel's question?

Comment: Final edition made, to have at least the written the solution, another option is that 
@fra-san writes the solution in another answer.

Comment: @Kes For future use: you should probably have edited your question, adding the content of the first comment you left on this answer. Comments can be deleted, and this answer could end up looking a bit illogical without them.

Comment: @Dasel Thanks. I'm not posting my own answer because it would not answer _the question_. Feel free to elaborate further on my comment.

Comment: @fra-san I think the `&&` was needed for this solution & therefore answered the question.
As soon as I tried `&&` as you suggested in your comment above it worked.
At that point I saw how this question might broadly become a confusing resource as the answer lay in the comments, not then, at that point in time, in the only suggested answer.
What to do in this situation? 
I could not get `case` to work, as suggested, though may be it can work.
@Dasel if you were to take out the first two suggestions in your answer that would make everything clear to me.

Comment: Modified the answer with only the final aswer.

Comment: Apart from that edit note (which I'm going to remove since it has no relevance to the subject matter and anyone can see the edit timestamp and the edit history, if they care), this answer is just a code dump without any explanation. I don't doubt the correctness of the code, but it might be useful for future readers to add some explanation of why that code is the answer.